# How to load certain JS resources only on specific pages in Grails 2.2.4

Tags: javascript, grails

On Grails 2.2.4 how can I load certain JS resources only on specific pages. Currently all JS files I use are loaded on all pages (even on the ones I don't need).

My `ApplicationResources` looks like this:

```
modules = {
    application {
        dependsOn "jquery", "jquery-ui", "emberjs","emberjsdata", "pjax", "highchart", "filetype", "theme"
        resource url:'js/application.js'
        resource url:'js/App.js'
        resource url:'js/bootstrap-select.js'
        resource url:'js/bootstrap-switch.js'
    }

    request {
        dependsOn "application"
        resource url: 'js/request.js'
    }

    lowside {
        dependsOn "application"
        resource url:'js/lowside.js'
    }

    pjax {
        resource url: 'js/jquery.pjax.js', disposition: "head"
    }

    highchart {
        resource url: 'js/highcharts.js', disposition: "head"
    }

    filetype {
        resource url: 'js/filestyle.js', disposition: "head"
    }

    emberjs {
        dependsOn 'jquery,handlebars'
        resource url: 'js/ember-latest-stable.js'
    }
    handlebars {
        resource url: 'js/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js'
    }
    emberjsdata{
        dependsOn 'emberjs'
        resource url: 'js/ember-data-latest.js'
    }

    theme {
        resource url: 'js/theme.js'
    }
}
```

on my layout page I do this:

```
<r:require module="application"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your layout and resources configured, Grails is doing exactly what it was designed to do. By requiring the `application` module in your (I assume) only layout page, every single resource will be included in every single GSP that is rendered. You have a couple of options to stop this from happening.

1. If a lot of your resources are only used on single pages, consider creating a module that only has the *common* Javascript or CSS resources that you need. This module should be required in the main layout. Then, on the individual pages that require the more niche resources, you can use a require tag in the `head` tag, just like you do in the layout page. For instance, let's say you only need highchart on one page. That page might look a little like this:

`<html>
      <head>
        ...
        <r:require module="highchart"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        ...
      </body>
    </html>`

2. If there are multiple pages that require a single resource (but the entire app does not require this resource), consider creating layouts for these groups of pages. This is especially effective if you have pages centered around a "feature" in your application. Going back to the example of highchart, let's say you have an "Analytics" section of your application where there are various pages that utilize highchart. You might create a layout file: `layouts/analytics.gsp` that looks something like this:

`<html>
      <head>
        ...
        <r:require modules="common,highchart"/>
        <r:layoutResources />
        <g:layoutHead/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <g:layoutBody/>
        <r:layoutResources/>
      </body>
    </html>`